# Vector Legend item names in QGIS Map Composer

Tags: qgis

Is it possible to get the text for a legend item to go over multiple lines? I have some long item names and I have a set legend width that I have to use.

Without being able to make the text go over multiple lines I am unable to get my legend to fit the page properly.

Edit:

I have added an image to better illustrate the problem. As you can see the text for area type one goes out of the box I have set up for a legend. Personally I think short names in legends work best, but project managers do not always agree with this.

[image]

Comment: Does using \n do anything?

Comment: That was my first thought too geographika. Unfortunately it doesn't appear to. Nor does <BR>

Comment: And the MapInfo trick of using chr$(13) doesnt help either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not supported yet, afaik. There is a whole list of enhancement wishes on the QGIS wiki: http://www.qgis.org/wiki/Ideas_for_enhancement_print_composer

Update:

This is now implemented in the developer version. Let's see if it will be in 1.8 release.

Comment: Glad to see it is on the list of enhancement wishes. Just hope it is picked as one of the ones they implement.